# How do I fix my static page

Tags: customization

I have tried a few option with static pages.

First i created a template called homepage.php and had it designed a certain way, and also on that template were the post. Then i created another template called news.php and this is the regular blog set up with the news post and navigation. When i set the front page to the homepage template the post didn't show up.

Next i created home.php and then created a page called News and everything in the index.php template i pllaced in the news.php, for the News page i selected the news.php template but nothing showed up

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to have a home page with it's own content and then the blog to be elsewhere on your site.

What you want to do is create a [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates). Call it `Home Page Template` or something like that and you can make the file whatever you'd like - maybe `template-homepage.php`. You may want to copy your `page.php` file and rename it, add in the template file header (see link above) and then start editing that page to be as you'd like the home page to be.

*As of Wordpress 3.4 you can actually just make a copy of `page.php`, create a folder in your theme called `templates`, and then drop the new file into that folder without doing anything else.*

The next step is to Create a Page. On the right side of the edit screen, you can select the **Page Template**. Choose the Page Template that you just created.

Then go to **Settings > Reading Settings**. You'll see the *Front Page Displays* section at the top. Select **A Static Page** and then you can choose that newly created page to be the front *Front Page*. At this point you should go and create another page, named Blog or News. **Don't** add any content to it or select a page template. Go back to the reading settings and select that new page as your *Posts Page*.

[image]

**Note:**
There are other ways to do what I just outlined, but that's my personal preference. Read about **[Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)** in Wordpress and there's always the Visual Guide below, which is a good way to tell which page template you need to create in order to achieve what you have in mind.

[image]

Comment: I have my homepage setup like this --> aliciakeys.com but at the end of the news i want to place a link that says "More News" and it goes to a page that has all the latest news including pagination.

Comment: Sure. After following the instructions above, in the home page template just add a link to the /blog/ or /news/ page. eg. `<a href="http://yoursite.com/blog/">More News</a>`